# Image corrupt when convert base64 string to image in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, image-upload

I am trying to convert base64 string to image in .net core but the resulted image is corrupted
Following is my code

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Image))
                {
                    string filePath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath+"/Image" , model.ImageName);
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, Convert.FromBase64String(model.Image));
                }
```

is there any other method to create image from base64 string and save to server in asp.net core?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and it works well.You could try below correct base64string to have a test and check whether you have a correct base64string

```
var image = "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";


var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(image);
string filePath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath + "/Image" , "testImage.jpeg");

using (var imageFile = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
{
    imageFile.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    imageFile.Flush();
}
```

Comment: you are right, problem is with base64string. I have tested with your string and it works fine. But when I select this image again and convert it to base64 it give me different string.
Actually I am posting form from angular to api and convert image to base64 in angular.

Comment: @Hunzla Sheikh So the problem is in your angular and the base64 string format may be incorrect(what is your base64 string?You need to remove the prefix).I suggest that you could post the necessary code and your string